# Shared Preferences data persistence after phone is switched off

Tags: android

Does *Shared Preferences* data remain stored if phone is **switched off** or **battery is taken out**??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

it will in the application's data so until you remove your application shared preference stored the data.

But keep in mind as you remove application from device then there is no data in shared preference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes : that's how most preferences are stored by the applications you are using everyday -- and those applications don't lose their preferences when you turn off your phone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It will persists until application is uninstall or memory is cleared.